# Output for removing zeros in array does not come as expected?

Tags: java, arrays

> Given an array of integers return an array in the same order with all 0's removed.

**Sample Input #1**

```
remove({1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,0,0,2})
```

**Sample Output #1**

```
{1,2,3,4,5,1,2,2}
```

**Sample Input #2**

```
remove({0,0,1,2})
```

**Sample Output #2**

```
{1,2}
```

**Sample Input #3**

```
remove({0,0,0,0})
```

**Sample Output #3**

```
{}
```

**MyApproach**

I first counted how many zeros are there and then I created a new array and added only those elements which are not zero.

But I am not getting correct output.

> Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong?

Below is my code for the above program:

```
public int[] remove(int[] arr)
{
 int count=0;
 for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 {
     if(arr[i]==0)
     {
         count++;
     }
 }
 int p[]=new int[arr.length-count];
 for(int m=0;m<p.length;)
 {
     if(arr[m]==0)
     {

         m++;
     }
     else
     {
          p[m]=arr[m];
           m++;
     }
 }
 return p;

 }


Parameters                  Actual Output   Expected Output


'{0,1,2,3,0,1}'               {0,1,2,3}      {1,2,3,1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two counters, one for where you are copying from and one for where you are copying to.

```
for (int n = 0, m = 0; m < p.length; m++)
    if (arr[m] != 0)
       p[n++] = arr[m];
```

or you can do

```
int n = 0;
for (int x : arr)
    if (x != 0)
        p[n++] = x;
```

In Java 8 you can do

```
public static int[] removeZero(int[] ints) {
    return IntStream.of(ints)
            .filter(i -> i != 0)
            .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this for removing zeros in your array:

```
public int[] remove(int[] array)
  {
     int j = 0;
     for( int i=0;  i<array.length;  i++ )
   {
    if (array[i] != 0)
        array[j++] = array[i];
   }
     int [] newArray = new int[j];
     System.arraycopy( array, 0, newArray, 0, j );
     return newArray;

 }
```